# kml google extensions not in schema

Tags: kml

The jurisdiction I live in published data using a Google globe.  The kml file they point to contains

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
     xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
         <gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink>
         <href>http://globe.information.qld.gov.au/qldglobe</href>
     </gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink>
</kml>
```

I can't find any reference to the gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink in any public documentation and I am having trouble using that with other standard kml, for example a Place.  I'd like a kml that pens this government globe and also adds a Place.

I'd like to be able to add this Place to the Above kml (ie. one kml file)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
<Placemark>
<description>Some nice place</description>
<Point>
<coordinates>153.0064595002,-27.4811714996,0</coordinates>
</Point>
<Style>
    <LabelStyle>
     <color>ff7fffff</color>
    </LabelStyle>
</Style>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 3):

The Google KML extensions can be found in Google's KML documentation:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kmlextensions

The complete XML schema for elements in this extension namespace is located at http://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd.

***gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink*** is **not** a documented part of the [Google KML extensions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kmlextensions) as defined in the namespace `http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2`.

Why don't you create a [KMZ](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives) file with a root KML file and the gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink loaded in a KML embedded in the KMZ file as an auxiliary file.

**Root KML file doc.kml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <NetworkLink>
            <Link>
                <href>engine.kml</href>
            </Link>
        </NetworkLink>

        <Placemark>
            <description>Some nice place</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>153.0064595002,-27.4811714996,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
            <Style>
                <LabelStyle>
                    <color>ff7fffff</color>
                </LabelStyle>
            </Style>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

And the google engine KML (engine.kml) like this:

**engine.kml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">

    <gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink>
        <href>http://globe.information.qld.gov.au/qldglobe</href>
    </gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink>

</kml>
```

**Update:** Since the `<gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink>` is special and undocumented it doesn't work as would other KML elements so it cannot appear as child to `<Document>` element or as target to `<NetworkLink>`. Likewise, if this element appears at the root level with a Document or Placemark following those Features are ignored.

Google announced it will discontinue the Google Maps Engine product in January 2016.

Comment: It doesn't ever load the network asset described in the undocumented gz:GoogleMapsEngineLink .  It loads the placemark but doesn't pull in the network asset.

Comment: Yeap, since the gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink element isn't standard it doesn't work in context of other elements. I'll ping Google and try to get clarification.

Comment: I've had confirmation from the Government that has sent the kml that "gx:GoogleMapsEngineLink does disable any further kml functionality" .

Comment: See my new answer below, since the www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2/ is a 404 error, it was very tricky to finally get my KML to validate.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get my KML to [Validate as valid XML](http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/) because my KML includes a gx (Google Extension) tag (`<gx:Tour>` for example), and www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2/ is a 404 error.
Here is what I finally got to validate after an hour of trial and error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" 
xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" 
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 http://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
```

I don't really know what I'm doing exactly, so I can't make any claims this is a kosher or legitimate fix, or whether that's all necessary. But it's the only way I could get it to validate.

Comment: Try [XmlValidate](https://github.com/docjason/XmlValidate) tool to validate your KML and KMZ files with gx: extensions. It rewrites the KML and refers to local copies of the XSDs to validate.

Comment: Note the http:// URL for XSD listed above redirects to this URL: `https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd` so appears redirections is not supported by Validome tool. Rewrite using correct URL.