# Why does my namespace for the KML gx extensions not work

Tags: kml, google-earth

I decided to validate my KML file, and it came back saying it couldn't find "http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" in the namespace area. When I type this url into my browser I get a not found. This url is widely published as the place to get the gx extensions. Why can't I see it ?

Comment: related question: [kml google extensions not in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801152/kml-google-extensions-not-in-schema)

Answer (score 0):

A [namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) in XML is a URI reference. A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is an identifier to an abstract or physical resource whereas a Uniform Resource Locators (URL) is a location to a physical resource.

The [Google KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference) defines the [Google Earth KML extensions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#kmlextensions) with the `xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"` namespace URI.

The URI `http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2` is not a physical URL that can be resolved to a web page but the XML schema for gx extensions can be found at this URL:

https://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd

The physical location of a schema can be specified using the *xsi:schemaLocation* attribute as shown in KML fragment below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"
 xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd
  http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 http://developers.google.com/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
...
</kml>
```